# Desserializar Objeto em array após json_encode

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho um array de objetos.

Porém antes de enviar esses objetos no array, faço `serialize()` em cada índice do array pois são objetos:

```
function serialize(){
    return json_encode(get_object_vars ($this));
}
```

Agora faço `json_encode` nesse array e envio a resposta de uma requisição

Agora vou recuperar esse array na página de resposta.

Mas preciso desserializar os objetos

Como fazer isso?

Estou recebendo o array assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"id":1,"ordem":"20191213221255","status":"OS Finalizada","dataEntrada":"2019-10-13","cliente":1,"equipamento":1,"defeitoRelatado":"Aparelho n\u00e3o liga","estado":"P\u00c9SSIMO","aprovado":"N\u00e3o","garantia":"Sim","analiseTecnico":"bacana","composicaoOrcamento":null,"valorOrcamento":null,"pgtoEntrada":null,"pgtoFinal":null,"dataSaida":"2019-10-16 00:10:00","obs":null}
    [1] =>   ....
)
```

Estou tentando como abaixo mas não deu certo!

```
$ordensSerializadas = json_decode( listar ( $_SESSION["token"] ), true);

$ordens = array();

foreach ( $ordensSerializadas as $ordem )
     $ordens[] = $ordem->unserialize();

print_r ($ordens);
```

**ERRO:**

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function unserialize() on string in D:\web\ctemcasb.com.br\acweb.php:156
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>D:\web\ctemcasb.com.br\acweb.php</b> on line <b>156</b><br />
```

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON não serializa o objeto, apenas representa como *string* o estado atual do mesmo. Se quiser mesmo serializar, você terá que utilizar as funções `serialize` e `unserialize`, ou bibliotecas de terceiros que possam fazer o processo análogo.

Se quiser manter o JSON, basta você tratá-lo do outro lado como JSON.

```php
foreach ( $ordensSerializadas as $ordem )
     $ordens[] = json_decode($ordem);
```

Mas isso pode ser diretamente influenciado pelo retorno da função `listar`, visto que você já fez o `json_decode` nele e não faria muito sentido processar o JSON por partes (talvez tenha mais coisa errada).

Comment: Foi mal @woss, vi que a resposta era a mesma então exclui a minha.

Comment: @LucasEmanuel Ah, vi que acabou editando... eu tinha dado o -1 apenas por estar errada na primeira versão, não por responder a mesma coisa.

Comment: blz, entendi! Era isso mesmo!
Obrigado!
Deu certo aqui!